# Regex validation and retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have regex string in c# like:

```
OVE.com: Purchase Confirmation \([0-9a-zA-Z\s\.]+ [0-9a-zA-Z]{17} PEDDLE LLC\)
```

Now, I want to retrieve a value which is formed by `[0-9a-zA-Z]{17}` in regex.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you describe how the result should look like or what the actual problem is? I don't really uderstand what you are asking - [0-9a-zA-Z]{17} already is regex ...

Comment: Look at `Regex.Groups[x].Value` and look for the part you are searching... (Replace the `x` with numbers starting at `0`)

Comment: I want to retrieve the value from source string which is in place of [0-9a-zA-Z]{17}.  @Fuzzzzel

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is using this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(.{17}) PEDDLE");
var m = regex.Match(s);
if(m.Success) 
{
    m.Groups[0].toString()); // <= this is your match.
}
```

Which would match the 17 chars before `PEDDLE`